# Can someone help me determine the cause of my Seg Fault in C and the meaning of the gdb output?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, gdb

[image]

When I run the program it prints out "SUCCESS!!!!" if it works alright, but I keep getting seg faults and I can't seem to figure out where. Can someone help me determine what exactly causes the signal SIGABRT and what is the most likely cause of why getting segmentation faults?

My code is written in c.

EDIT:
In my main code on line 97 I have the function fclose(fp) but I should have already read through it in another function. Here is my code from main.c:

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
if(fp = fopen(full_filename, "r")){
    Node* tree = NULL;
    tree = parser(fp);
    printTree(tree, 1);

    fclose(fp);
}
else
    printf("Error file DNE\n");

return 0;
```

The function parser gets the file pointer and sends that file pointer to another function called scanner. Then scanner creates a list of words from that file. Then parser checks grammar of the words.

EDIT 2: 
I got rid of fclose(fp) in main and when I ran it in gdb, I got no errors. But when I ran it without gdb I still get a seg fault.

Comment: Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: According to gdb the problem lies in file `main.c` line number 97. It looks like it has something to do with invalid pointer. Can you show us the code? That way people will be able to help you

Comment: Please remove the picture and post text as text. Use the [edit] button to do so. Check [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting tips (you want the whole snipped to be formatted as a code block).

Comment: If your code is C, don't tag your questions with other languages.

Comment: Check `parser` and see if if `fclose`-s the `fp` you passed in as a parameter. Only one place (traditionally, the same code block the `fopen`-ed it) should do that. If you `fclose` twice on the same `fp` (such as in `parser` and then again in the posted code) with no intervening `fopen` you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: flose is not closed twice. But i got rid of fclose in main and I got no errors using gdb but I still get a seg fault when I run the code not using gdb.

Comment: In your updated code when you ran without gdb does it create any corefile. If not do necessary configuration so that it generates one and then you can open it with gdb to check where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

There isn't too much information, but looking at the trace it would be my guess that you are trying to close a file with `fclose()` or `iofclose()`, and the file may not exist, or it is not open.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I added more information on what the program does. But I send the file pointer to another function and read through that file. Then I close that file pointer in main.

Answer (score 0):

> Conclusion

The problem must lie in your parser() function. It seems it is altering your file pointer and making it invalid.

> Explanation

I state this because I it can't enter your `if(fp = fopen(full_filename, "r"))` statement unless the pointer is valid, but when you try to close it, the pointer seems to be invalid.

> Note that

The only line which is able to affect your pointer is the one showing the folowing:

```
tree = parser(fp);
```